# passing function to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, function, conditional-statements

I'm checking a tag if it exists the tags should exist but then it goes to the exists and non exist condition this is my code:

```
function _checkTagsExists( $tag , $chimptags ){

foreach( $chimptags as $key => $value ){

  if( $value == $tag ){
    $response[ 'value' ] = $value;
    $response[ 'exists' ] = 1;
    $response[ 'tag' ] = $tag;
    $response[ 'interests_id' ] = $key;
  }

}
return $response;
}
$actags = array('existingtag1','existingtag2');
$interests = array('key1'=>'existingtag1','key2'=>'existingtag2');
foreach( $actags as $actag ){

      $tagscheck = _checkTagsExists( $actag , $interests);


      //if tag is already existing
      if( $tagscheck[ 'exists' ] == 1 ){

        $message[] = "exists";


      }else{
        $message[] = "NOT exist";


      }
}
var_dump($message);
```

this code results in

```
array{0 => "exists", 1 => "NOT exist"}
```

but it should be all exists

Comment: You should reword your question since it's actually difficult to understand.

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked:  array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "exists" [1]=> string(6) "exists" }

Comment: OMG yeah i also tried it it worked hmm I need to rephrase the code because I just used simple arrays

Comment: Even before you update your question, your process seems very convoluted.  Have you looked into `array_intersect()` and `array_diff()` as the shortest path to your goal?  I say this because, if this ends up being one of those "Read The Manual" questions that new members are infamous for, I'm probably going to downvote it.

Comment: sad part with this is this is a new account I have an old account but then I was using another email from another company. and here's someone with so much reputation scolding a newbie. I wouldn't have asked this question if I already spent  about 4 hours trying to figure out what's wrong with the code

Comment: @AndreiLeyba I apologize for falsely assuming you are new to stackoverflow.  With the combination of confusing English, near zero rep points/badges, no _Informed_ badge, and code that fails to replicate the problem, surely you can understand my assumption.   As far as SO rep points are concerned, I am very much a newbie.  I look forward to your update and hopefully I can lend a hand -- because I am here to help people.

Answer (score 0):

solved this by adding a break in the loop if a tag is found so that it will no reiterate to the other value of the array